# Axon 4 replay specify end token instead of start token

Tags: java, cqrs, event-sourcing, axon

In my usecase I have to get the state of an aggregate before a certain point in time. Thus I like to specify the end token for Axon to replay events, instead of start token. Is this even possible with the Replay API, the only examples I found thus far is getting the events from a specific token till the end of the stream, I want it backwards.

- 2021-15-10T11:00:00 Create Event <-- Start
- 2021-15-10T12:00:00 Update Event
- 2021-15-10T13:00:00 Update Event <-- End
- 2021-15-10T14:00:00 Update Event

I haven't found anything on the docs and any sample projects that this is supported. Have I overlooked this or should I build my own solution with re-triggering the aggregate with specified events?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: AFAIK, you are not able to specify the end of it as it will always try to handle events up to the head of the stream, meaning all of the events. May I ask you what you are trying to achieve with that? Maybe there is a better way of doing it.

Comment: I am not that familiar with event sourcing so it might be there is a better way, I am open to suggestions.

The use case I am trying to implement is that we want the state of an aggregate at a certain point in time. When called on an endpoint with a date I want to replay everything from start to the last events before the given date.

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed possible by configuring the token, you can even tell the API to start at a certain point in time.  If you take a look at the StreamableMessageSource interface, you can see that it has the following operations:

```
StreamableMessageSource#createTailToken()
StreamableMessageSource#createHeadToken()
StreamableMessageSource#createTokenAt(Instant)
StreamableMessageSource#createTokenSince(Duration)
```

You can find more info around this topic in the [Reference guide](https://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/v/master/axon-framework/events/event-processors/streaming#token-configuration)

Comment: I can only see an initial token, I am looking for a way to specify a start and end. Are there any examples on this?

Comment: You can start the replay at a certain moment in time using Instant or Duration. You can not configure the end though but you can add a filter if needed. You can take a look at a Saga configuration example [here](https://github.com/AxonIQ/code-samples/blob/master/saga/src/main/java/io/axoniq/dev/samples/saga/ProcessOrderSagaConfig.java).

Answer (score 0):

As already became apparent from Yvonne her reply, Axon Framework's [Replay API](https://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/axon-framework/events/event-processors/streaming#replaying-events) does not provide functionality like this. Not out of the box, at least.

There's a little confusion in your question, however.
Do you want to recreate an aggregate in the sense of the command model, or are you talking about a query model?

If it's the former, then I'd like to state that recreating the Command Model until a given point in time wouldn't do justice to the decision-making logic (in most scenarios). The Command Model's aggregate should portray *all* changes to deduce how to react to the following command.

Having said that, I think you're not looking to reconstruct the `@Aggregate` annotated class within your framework. Instead, you have a query model that's a one-to-one mapping of a single aggregate instance's events that you're looking to recreate. Until a given point in time, of course.

To achieve this, you could construct an `AnnotationEventHandlerAdapter` (internal Axon Framework class) and manually invoke the handle method for a filtered stream of events. You have the power to deduce what goes in the filtered event stream, so also whether it should stop after a given timestamp.

Building something like this could be done like so:

```java
class QueryModelReplayer {

    private final EventStore eventStore;

    QueryModelReplayer(EventStore eventStore) {
        this.eventStore = eventStore;
    }

    public MyQueryModel createQueryModel(String aggregateId, Instant endPoint) {
        MyQueryModel queryModel = new MyQueryModel();
        AnnotationEventHandlerAdapter queryModelEventHandler = new AnnotationEventHandlerAdapter(queryModel);

        DomainEventStream domainEventStream = eventStore.readEvents(aggregateId);

        domainEventStream.asStream()
                         .filter(trackedEvent -> trackedEvent.getTimestamp().isBefore(endPoint))
                         .forEach(trackedEvent -> {
                             try {
                                 queryModelEventHandler.handle(trackedEvent);
                             } catch (Exception e) {
                                 // deal with exception...
                             }
                         });
        
        return queryModel;
    }

    public static class MyQueryModel {

        private String myString;
        private Integer myInt;
        // or any state you'd need really

        @EventHandler
        public void on(String event) {
            myString = event;
        }

        @EventHandler
        public void on(Integer event) {
            myInt = event;
        }
        // or any event handler you have really
    }
}
```

The above will allow you to construct a Query Model based on a specific aggregate's event stream, stopping at a certain point in time.
If the event stream should consist out of **all** events from **any** aggregate, you'd use the `EventStore#openStream` method instead.

As you see, this is quite some stuff to do.
The reason for this not to exist in Axon Framework is that it's quite a hefty tool. It will read an entire aggregate's event stream every time a query is performed, with queries typically happening quite often. Sure, command handling does the same, but there are built-in snapshotting and caches on that end to simplify the process. Axon doesn't know whether your Query Model is based on a single aggregate stream or the entire event stream. Especially in the latter case, you'd be retrieving *the whole event stream* every time you'd query the model.

Concluding, you could use the above to solve your use case. Whether it's the best tool for the job is a second question, though. If you anticipate needing a Query Model from point-in-time x-to-y very frequently, looking into a time-series database might be a smarter tool for the job.

That's my two cents, hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your extensive answer. I am not trying to reconstruct the aggregate each time. I want to replay the events of a certain aggrgate to get the state from first to that point in time. I might mis-use the replay API for this. Any suggestions if there is a better way to do this?

Comment: Sure thing Dave, glad to help! Let me ask some follow-ups to better understand your scenario. With 'aggregate', do you mean the `@Aggregate` annotated class in your application that is handling commands?

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks. I still have another question though, so please bear with me. So, what do you exactly require the aggregate's state for at a given point in time?

Comment: I want that at a given point the state is equal to all replayed events before the date. Is that what you mean?

Comment: No, not entirely. What I am looking for is who/what is requiring that state. What's the purpose you need it to be at a given point? Is it to handle a command/validate before an operation? Is it to return state to somebody or something?

Comment: It is to return state to somebody

Comment: Gotcha. Well, assuming you also want to do CQRS in your application, then that actually means you are dealing with a Query Model. Hence, using Axon's aggregate directly isn't recommended, since this is the Command Model. Instead, you can create a dedicated Event Handler that updates a projection that allows you to jump to different points in time. Using the sample I gave in my response would in this case suit your needs, as you don't need to permanently store the view if I understood you correctly.